# Why is file access in WebBroker-ISAPI-Module only working in separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, iis, isapi

I'm developing my first ISAPI web module with Delphi 11.1 and WebBroker, and want to write logs to the file system. For testing purposes I made the following procedure `TryWriteFile`, testing if I can create a file in the `WebApplicationDirectory`:

```
procedure WriteMyFile;
var
  fname: string;
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fname := TPath.Combine(WebApplicationDirectory, 'myfile.log');
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fname, fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
  fs.Write([$54,$65,$73,$74,$0D,$0A], 6); { T e s t CR LF }
  fs.Free;
end;
```

Now, I try calling `WriteMyFile` in the DefaultHandler action, but get an "access denied" Exception:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  WriteMyFile;  //==> exception: access denied!
  Response.Content := 'no error!';
end;
```

When I call `WriteMyFile` from a separate thread instead, **it works. The file is created correctly**:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  thr: TThread;
begin
  //WriteMyFile;  //==> exception: access denied!

  thr := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(WriteMyFile); //works, file is created!
  thr.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  thr.Start;
  thr.WaitFor;
  thr.Free;
  Response.Content := 'no error!';
end;
```

So my question is: Why? Does it have something to do with Windows folder permissions? And if so, how can those be different in different threads?

### My configuration

IIS configuration:

1. ISAPI restrictions set to "Allow unspecified ISAPI modules"
2. new application pool `MYPOOL`

   - no managed code
   - 32bit enabled (since my dll is compiled to 32bit)
3. new Website "My Website"

   - physical path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MYPOOL\` with added "Modify" permission for `IIS AppPool\MYPOOL`
   - Handler Mappings: Execution allowed.

Both IIS and Delphi 11.1 Alexandria are running on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: by the way: implementing `WriteMyFile` with `AssignFile` has the same effect.

Comment: Try calling [GetUserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew) within `WriteMyFile()` to ensure that the user associated with current thread is your aplication pool's identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit: it was an IIS configuration problem. I didn't configure Authentication for my *virtual directory* (which is a different thing than Authentication for the *physical path*).

- I went to "My Website", then "Authentication", and set "Anonymous Authentication" to "Application Pool Identity".
- After this change, `WriteMyFile` always works, regardless of which thread is calling it.
- Source: [this old edn article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200201143210/http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40873).

The original behavior is still weird, though. But that "just" seems to be an IIS quirk, not related to my code (nor Delphi).

### Update

[Thank you Peter Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78030904/why-is-file-access-in-webbroker-isapi-module-only-working-in-separate-thread?noredirect=1#comment137570129_78030904) for providing a method to confirm this! The default Authentication for my *virtual directory* was `IUSR`, which is exactly, what `GetUserName` spits out:

```
uses Winapi.Windows;
var  usrname: string;

procedure GetMyUserName;
var
  len: Cardinal;
begin
  len := 100;
  SetLength(usrname, len);
  GetUserNameW(PWideChar(usrname), len);
  SetLength(usrname, len);
end;

procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  thr: TThread;
begin
  GetMyUserName;
  Response.Content := usrname;  //==> "IUSR"

  thr := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(WriteMyFile);
  thr.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  thr.Start;
  thr.WaitFor;
  thr.Free;
  Response.Content := usrname;  //==> "MYPOOL"
end;
```

So apparently, different threads can be associated with different authentication identities.

Comment: Does this phenomenon/bug category have a name, like "sneaky identity"?

Comment: in 4 hours, I can :)